# How to build UINavigationController-like behaviour in Android?

Tags: android, uinavigationcontroller, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm aware the View structure for Android is completely different (ie. Activities instead of View Controllers) but I need to create a Navigation Bar that persists between views.

Is the best way really to have just one single Activity and then a lot of Fragments?

If so, has this implementation already been done somewhere else that I can use? It seems like something that would come up a lot as I've seen numerous Android apps do this.

Answer (score 3):

I made a [Framework (github)](https://github.com/ericalarcon/AndroidBasicFrameworkExample) to provide a hierarchical navigation pattern, with animations to provide sense of navigation, rather than launching new Activities every time.

[image: Android Basic Framework Image]

Here's how to use it:

- Add the framework to your project as a Module
- Add a new Java class in your project ("File - New - Java Class"). 
  *Note: If you are editing the Activity.java file that provides you the template, delete all its implementations and leave it empty.*
- Make it extend NavigationActivity
- Implement all the NavigationActivity abstract methods

(*in Android Studio if you click Alt + insert and select implement - methods all the function definitions are automatically generated*).

```
public class NavigationTest extends NavigationActivity{
    @Override
    public Fragment firstFragment() {
        //return the first fragment that will be shown  

    }

    @Override
    public Boolean showBackButtonInFirstFragment() {
        //show back button already in the first Fragment
        //set to True if this activity is called by another Activity
        //the back button will then pop back to the previous Activity

    }

    @Override
    public Boolean showMasterDetailLayoutInTablets() {
        //set to false if you don't want a master-detail layout in tablets

    }
}
```

#### Presenting a new Fragment

You can present a new fragment (with a nice animation) by calling the `pushFragment` method from NavigationActivity.

```
public void pushFragment(Fragment newFragment, animationType animation, boolean showAsDetailFragmentIfPossible)
```

`newFragment` (`Fragment`): New Fragment that will be presented

`animation` (`animationType`): Animation type enum: `RIGHT_TO_LEFT`, `BOTTOM_TO_TOP`, `FLIP`

`showAsDetailFragmentIfPossible` (`boolean`): If set as True, the user is in a Tablet, and you are using a master-detail layout, the Fragment will be shown in the detail Fragment (the panel in the right)!

Since you can access the activity from any Fragment with the `getActivity()` method, **you can show a new Fragment from the currently displaying Fragment**.
For example you can put this code within a button click listener:

```
NextFragment f = new NextFragment();
NavigationActivity nav =((NavigationActivity)getActivity());
nav.pushFragment(f,NavigationActivity.animationType.RIGHT_TO_LEFT,false);
```

You don't have to worry about implementing the back button behaviour. This is handled automatically by the `NavigationActivity` class.